# How to cache database translations on yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to  cache database translations on yii2

I tried the following but not worked

```
'i18n' => [
            'class' => Zelenin\yii\modules\I18n\components\I18N::className(),
            'languages' => ['en', 'ar', 'fr'],
            'sourceMessageTable' => 'source_message',
            'messageTable' => 'message',
            'cache' => 'cache'

        ],
```

Comment: I think you should explicitly mention used extension and link for it even it can be recognized from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in Zelenin i18n module. If you look at Module.php file, you can see:

```
        $this->translations['*'] = [
            'class' => DbMessageSource::className(),
            'sourceMessageTable' => $this->sourceMessageTable,
            'messageTable' => $this->messageTable,
            'on missingTranslation' => $this->missingTranslationHandler
        ];
```

in `init()` method. This Code set DbMessageSource options and there are no any options about caching. Module have no any caching options too.

If you change this code to:

```
        $this->translations['*'] = [
            'class' => DbMessageSource::className(),
            'sourceMessageTable' => $this->sourceMessageTable,
            'messageTable' => $this->messageTable,
            'enableCaching' => true,
            'cachingDuration' => 3600,
            'on missingTranslation' => $this->missingTranslationHandler
        ];
```

Cache will work. Some `SELECT` messages will gone from debug list.

Comment: The better way is not to modify zelenin component. You can change yii config (common or frontend) i18n section to this:'i18n' => ['class' => Zelenin\yii\modules\I18n\components\I18N::className(), 'translations' => ['*' => [code like in my answer]]]

Answer (score -1):

The Yii [documentation for i18n db messages](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-dbmessagesource.html#$cache-detail) says that the property `cache` only has meaning when the property `cacheDuration` is not zero. I suggest you set this value, so;

```
'i18n' => [
        'class' => Zelenin\yii\modules\I18n\components\I18N::className(),
        'languages' => ['en', 'ar', 'fr'],
        'sourceMessageTable' => 'source_message',
        'messageTable' => 'message',
        'cache' => 'cache',
        'cacheDuration' => 3600

    ],
```